# Generate Bezier Curve with specified length and number of points

Tags: java, bezier, curve

How would I adjust this code to take not only number of points in Bezier Curve but also target length.
It should extend curve if shorter than given length and make it shorter if longer than given length.
The points in float arrays are in format XYXYXY...

I took the code from [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25237/Bezier-Curves-Made-Simple) and edited slightly

```
public float[] Bezier2D(float[] b, int pts) {
  float[] p = new float[pts*2];
  int npts = b.length/2;
  int icount, jcount;
  float step, t;

  icount = 0;
  t = 0;
  step = 1f / (pts - 1);

  for(int i = 0; i != pts; i++) { 
    if((1.0 - t) < 5e-6) t = 1.0;

    jcount = 0;
    p[icount] = 0.0;
    p[icount + 1] = 0.0;
    for(int j = 0; j != npts; j++) {
      float basis = bernstein(npts - 1, j, t);
      p[icount] += basis * b[jcount];
      p[icount + 1] += basis * b[jcount + 1];
      jcount = jcount +2;
    }

    icount += 2;
    t += step;
  }
  return p;
}
```

Comment: It is not clear how your points should be considered. In linked example points are control points of curve and define it uniquely. Perhaps you can reformulate your question describing real problem.

Comment: Shorten/lengthen _how_? Do you want the code to magically reposition the points that define the polynomial, or do you just want to run the curve over a `t` interval [0,L] where L is less or greater than 1 to ensure the correct curve length?